# Would LAMP stack break my daily use Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: desktop-environments, lamp

If I install LAMP in my Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop and make it as my web development environment, would it break my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop?

Comment: That depends on what YOU mess up, doesn't it?

Comment: First, What do you mean by "breaking of Ubuntu Desktop" ? and secondly, I use LAMP and everything works perfectly. If you are looking for a detailed guide on Installing LAMP on Ubuntu 16.04, read this : [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04](LAMP on Ubuntu 16.04) .

Comment: For my test environment, I use guest virtualbox Ubuntu Server and then I run it inside my Ubuntu Desktop Host machine to make it safer. Though I don't want to setup ftp and ssh anymore and to eat up my resources. I wanted to directly test it in my host machine Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. Would it be safe? In MS Windows we use Xampp or Wampp to test our web. In Ubuntu its LAMP. if I install it in my host machine desktop and do my web development, would it mess up my Ubuntu Desktop?

Comment: @ProjectRK Include these additional details in your question please; they are important for figuring out if LAMP will "break your desktop". As your question currently stands, it is too vague in my opinion.

Comment: @ProjectRK, I know what you mean. Unfortunately I can't answer your question properly anymore, because it is closed, but if you want to make sure that the dependencies are not going to mess up your system, you can always use a virtual machine, or if you want more flexibility and performance, an lxc container. With the right settings, you can link your apache root directory to somewhere on your desktop, and whatever you write in there will appear in your LAMP based website.

Comment: @ProjectRK: I had the same problem, and I just wrote an script which you will probably find interesting, because I think that it does exactly what you want. It builds a LXD test environment and creates you an linked folder in your home, from where you can work safely. Check out here: http://github.com/julen/ll4d